# Windows XP - Restricted File Renaming

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

When I try to rename some files via Windows Explorer (I am using Windows XP), I come across some files on very rare occasions whereby I can only add a few characters to before I can progress no further.

For example, if I want to rename:

```
AFileName.doc
```

to:

```
thisIsANewVersionOfFileName.doc
```

I am only able to get as far as:

```
thiAFileName.doc
```

I have experimented with a few 'affected' files and have deduced the following:

- the length of the name makes no difference;
- it apparently affects any file type (.doc, .xls, .pdf, etc);
- each file is located in a different directory

  - file which are both 'shallow' and 'deep' in their respective directories can be affected;
- each file does not have any restrictions, such as read-only, password protection from within its respective application (Word, Excel, Adobe Reader).

I would like some suggestions as to what could be causing this as I need to rename said files but am unable to do so due to this problem.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after a quick googling I found this:

> Point A: The limit of 255 characters for Windows XP or 260 character limit for Windows Vista applies to the entire filepath and not just the filename.

[Limitations With Long File Names on Windows [Must Read for Podcasters]](http://labnol.blogspot.se/2006/10/limitations-with-long-file-names-on.html)

Comment: Thank you, but my first bullet point states the length of the filename doesn't affect it as this was the first thing that I suspected when the problem arose.

Comment: So you checked to make sure that whole filepath does not make up to 255 characters? Just asking since the bullet just states that the length of the filename makes no difference.

Comment: In fact, having checked again, you are indeed correct.  Thank you.